# Nuxt 3 modal / prop not updating properly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have a modal component that takes a prop to display the modal i also have the modal emitting a close function. All works well until I change page route and go back to the page that houses the modal. For some reason it does not show again even though the prop values look to be updating in the vue dev tools.

modal on page:

```
<script setup>
const subgroupModal = ref(false);

    const toggleModal = () => {
      subgroupModal.value = !subgroupModal.value;
    };
    
    const closeModal = () => {
      subgroupModal.value = false;
    };
    </script>


<template>

                  <button
                    @click="toggleModal"
                  >
                    <el-icon :size="30">
                      <el-icon-circle-plus-filled
                        class="relative text-orange top-[1px]"
                      />
                    </el-icon>
                  </button>

     <ContentModal @close-modal="closeModal" :modalActive="subgroupModal"
            >modal content</ContentModal>
 </template>
```

Modal component

```
<script setup>
  const props = defineProps({
    modalActive: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true
    }
  });

  const emit = defineEmits(['closeModal']);
  const close = () => {
    emit('closeModal');
  };
</script>

<template>
  <Teleport to="body">
    <Transition
      enter-from-class="opacity-0"
      leave-to-class="opacity-0"
      enter-active-class="transition duration-300"
      leave-active-class="transition duration-300"
    >
      <div
        v-if="modalActive"
        class="fixed z-50 flex items-start justify-center w-full h-full bg-black bg-opacity-60"
      >
        <div
          class="flex bg-white flex-col absolute top-[10%] md:top-[20%] sm:max-w-[1160px] w-[calc(100%-2.25rem)] pb-8 md:pb-12"
        >
          <div class="flex justify-end pt-3 pr-3 mb-3 md:mb-8">
            <button type="button"  @click="close">
              <el-icon :size="55">
                <el-icon-close-bold class="text-orange" />
              </el-icon>
            </button>
          </div>
          <slot></slot>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Transition>
  </Teleport>
</template>
```

Comment: 'All works well until I change page route and go back to the page that houses the modal.'

Sorry, but I'm not quite sure what this means. Would you mind clarifying it for me? Reading your codes, it should work as expected and when you change route and go back to the modal on page. You can need to click the modal trigger to show it.

Comment: So if go to the page >Trigger the modal > Close the modal > navigate to another page > navigate back to page with modal and try to trigger the modal again. It does not show. 

Anyway it was something to do with the Teleport. I removed that and it works as should. Thanks